# Spark Worker process is receiving SIGTERM

Tags: apache-spark

Spark worker process is receiving SIGTERM although no manual kill command has been run.

```
Exception in thread "dispatcher-event-loop-9" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.zip.ZipCoder.getBytes(ZipCoder.java:80)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(ZipFile.java:310)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(JarFile.java:240)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getJarEntry(JarFile.java:223)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:1005)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:212)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:365)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.safelyCall(Inbox.scala:206)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.process(Inbox.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher$MessageLoop.run(Dispatcher.scala:216)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2128)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getPrivateMethod(ObjectStreamClass.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$1700(ObjectStreamClass.java:72)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:494)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:365)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:602)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$deserialize$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:270)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.deserialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:319)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$deserialize$1.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:269)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.deserialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:268)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.RequestMessage$.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:603)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.internalReceive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:654)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.receive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:646)
at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processOneWayMessage(TransportRequestHandler.java:178)
at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:107)
at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead(TransportChannelHandler.java:118)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
22/12/24 00:46:43 ERROR Worker: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
2/12/24 00:46:51 INFO ExecutorRunner: Killing process!
22/12/24 00:46:51 INFO ExecutorRunner: Killing process!
22/12/24 00:46:51 INFO ExecutorRunner: Killing process!
22/12/24 00:46:51 INFO ExecutorRunner: Killing process!
.....
22/12/24 00:46:51 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

Have trimmed the logs above it.
We don't have any cluster manager for Spark cluster. We have 2 spark master nodes(active and standby) and a few worker nodes. Deploy mode is cluster.

SPARK VERSION - 2.2.1

Comment: Are you running on dataproc?

Comment: No . It's running on vm in private cloud.

Comment: 1. Was the worker running any tasks while receiving sigterm?
2. Are these logs from the executor or the driver?
3. By no resource manager do you mean you use spark standalone?

Comment: 1. Yes it was trying to launch the executor but that executor was failing with this msg :- Executor app-*(trimmed the app name) finished with state EXITED message Command exited with code 1 exitStatus 1. It was repeatedly failing again and again. (Have added more logs in the question)
2. These logs are from worker process (which can run both multiple drivers/executors). 
3. Yes standalone. Using Spark's own resource manager .